# when is the paint method called when using JFrame?

Tags: java

Listen, I'm brand new to Java. I've been basically a spreadsheet programmer for the past five years using VBA.  I know programming logic, not the intricacies of the language.  Help me please.  Class assignment:  Write program that will ask user how many houses they want to build.  Ask user if they want to include a tree next to their houses.  Build the number of houses and number of trees.  My code doesn't work.  If I enter '1' for the number of houses, it prints 2, any number over two and it does weird things. The tree function seems to work fine, just the number of trees to be "built" doesn't.

```
package javasrc_jacob_loden;    

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics; 
//import java.util.Scanner;
/*
 * 1)  Prompt user to enter the number of houses they would like to build using JOptionPane. Store as integer.
 * 2)  Ask user if they would like to include a tree next to their new houses.
 * 3)  Modules to load arrays with initial house coordinates.
 * 4)  Module to load arrays with initial tree coordinates.
 * 5)  Module to determine the size of an array.
 * 6)  Module to loop and load array with next house build coordinates.
 * 7)  Module to loop and load array with next tree build coordinates.  
 * 8)  Module to print the total number of houses built.
 */

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class newNeighborhoodBuilder extends JFrame{

    static int Roof[][] = new int[2][3];
    static int houseDimensions[][] = new int[6][4];
    static int windowFrame[][] = new int[4][2];
    static int tree[][] = new int[2][3];
    static int treeTrunk[][] = new int[2][4];
    static int treeYesNoResult;
    static int houses;
    boolean plantTree;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String numOfHouses;
        //int houses;


            //1)  Prompt user to enter the number of houses they would like to build using JOptionPane. Store as integer.
            numOfHouses = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many houses would you like to build?");
                houses = Integer.parseInt(numOfHouses);

            //2)  Ask user if they would like to include a tree next to their new houses.
            int treeYesNo = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
            treeYesNoResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,  "Would you like to plant trees next to your new houses?", "Question", treeYesNo);

            //3)Modules to load arrays with initial house coordinates.
            //Roof = loadInitialRoofDimensions(Roof);
            //houseDimensions = loadInitialHouseDimensions(houseDimensions);
            //windowFrame = loadInitialWindowFrameDimensions(windowFrame);
            //tree = loadInitialTree(tree);
            //treeTrunk = loadInitialTreeTrunk(treeTrunk);


            newNeighborhoodBuilder buildTheHouses = new newNeighborhoodBuilder();
            buildTheHouses.setVisible(true);

    }

            public void paint(Graphics canvas){
                //setVisible(true);
                //setSize(800, 400);
                //setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                System.out.println(houses);
                //int i = 1;

            for(int i=0; i<houses; i++){
                if(plantTreeYesNo()==true){
                    canvas.setColor(Color.green);
                    canvas.fillPolygon(tree[0], tree[1], tree[0].length);
                    canvas.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                    canvas.fillPolygon(treeTrunk[0], treeTrunk[1], treeTrunk[0].length);
                }


                    canvas.setColor(Color.blue);
                    canvas.fillPolygon(Roof[0], Roof[1], Roof[0].length);
                    canvas.setColor(Color.RED);
                    canvas.fillPolygon(houseDimensions[0], houseDimensions[1], houseDimensions[0].length);
                    canvas.setColor(Color.darkGray);
                    canvas.fillPolygon(houseDimensions[2], houseDimensions[3], houseDimensions[0].length);
                    canvas.setColor(Color.lightGray);
                    canvas.fillPolygon(houseDimensions[4], houseDimensions[5], houseDimensions[0].length);
                    canvas.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    canvas.drawPolyline(houseDimensions[2],  houseDimensions[3],  houseDimensions[0].length);
                    canvas.drawPolyline(windowFrame[0],  windowFrame[1],  windowFrame[0].length);
                    canvas.drawPolyline(windowFrame[2],  windowFrame[3],  windowFrame[0].length);
                    canvas.drawPolygon(houseDimensions[4], houseDimensions[5], houseDimensions[0].length);

                        Roof = moveHouse(Roof);
                        houseDimensions = moveHouse(houseDimensions);
                        windowFrame = moveHouse(windowFrame);
                        tree = moveHouse(tree);
                        treeTrunk = moveHouse(treeTrunk);

            }
            //System.exit(0);


        }
            //Constructor
            public newNeighborhoodBuilder(){
                //setVisible(true);
                setSize(800, 400);
                setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                Roof = loadInitialRoofDimensions(Roof);
                houseDimensions = loadInitialHouseDimensions(houseDimensions);
                windowFrame = loadInitialWindowFrameDimensions(windowFrame);
                tree = loadInitialTree(tree);
                treeTrunk = loadInitialTreeTrunk(treeTrunk);

                }



        //5)  Module to loop and load array with next house build coordinates.
        //6)  Module to loop and load array with next tree build coordinates. 
        public static int[][] moveHouse(int[][] movers){
            int[][] shiftX = new int[movers.length][movers[0].length];
            shiftX = movers;
            switch (shiftX.length){
            case 6:
                for(int i=0; i<shiftX[0].length; i++){
                    shiftX[0][i] = shiftX[0][i]+200;
                }
                for(int j=0; j<shiftX[0].length; j++){
                    shiftX[2][j] = shiftX[2][j]+200;
                }
                for(int k=0; k<shiftX[0].length; k++){
                    shiftX[4][k] = shiftX[4][k]+200;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                for(int l=0; l<shiftX[0].length; l++){
                    shiftX[0][l] = shiftX[0][l]+200;
                }
                for(int m=0; m<shiftX[0].length; m++){
                    shiftX[2][m] = shiftX[2][m]+200;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                for(int n=0; n<shiftX[0].length; n++){
                    shiftX[0][n] = shiftX[0][n]+200;
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.exit(0);

            }
            return shiftX;
        }
        public static boolean plantTreeYesNo(){
            if(treeYesNoResult==0){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        //3)Modules to load arrays with initial house coordinates.
        public static int[][] loadInitialRoofDimensions(int[][] a){
            int[][] Roof = {{120, 180, 240},//x roof
                    {100, 80, 100}};// y roof
            a = Roof;
            return a;
        }



        public static int[][] loadInitialHouseDimensions(int[][] b){
            int houseDimensions[][] = {{130, 130, 230, 230},//x house box
                                        {160, 100, 100, 160},//y house box
                                        {155, 155, 180, 180},//x door
                                        {160, 120, 120, 160},//y door
                                        {200, 200, 220, 220},//x window
                                        {120, 140, 140, 120}};//y window
            b = houseDimensions;
            return b;
        }

        public static int[][] loadInitialWindowFrameDimensions(int[][] c){
            int windowFrame[][] = {{200, 220},//x horizontal window pane
                                    {130, 130},//y horizontal window pane
                                    {210, 210},//x vertical window pane
                                    {120, 140}};// y vertical window pane
            c = windowFrame;
            return c;
        }
        //4)Module to load arrays with initial tree coordinates.
        public static int[][] loadInitialTree(int[][] d){
            int tree[][] = {{250, 270, 290},//x tree green
                            {140, 80, 140}};//y tree green
            d = tree;
            return d;
        }

        public static int[][] loadInitialTreeTrunk(int[][] e){
            int treeTrunk[][] = {{265, 265, 275, 275},//x tree trunk
                                {160, 140, 140, 160}};//y tree trunk
            e = treeTrunk;
            return e;
        }
        //5)  Module to determine the size of an array.
        public static int arrayColumnSize(int[][] howBig){
            int howManyRows = howBig.length;
            List<Integer> howBigList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int i=0; i<howBig.length; i++) {
                 //fill howBigList
                 for (int j=0; j<howBig[i].length; j++) { 
                    howBigList.add(howBig[i][j]); 
                }
            }
          int rowCount = howBigList.size()/howManyRows;

        return rowCount;
        }


}
```

Comment: I've asked google and the Java API but get conflicting results...when, exactly, will paint() execute?  How do I control the execution?

Comment: This is a VERY rough draft...I have a method at the end that I didn't need.  Turns out I can find the number of columns in a 2d array by asking array[0].length....didn't now that.